# Android 2 imageviews to 1 canvas alignment issue

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have 2 imageviews. 1 ImageView is static which will always be placed at the center horizontal and vertical we will call this Image A. The other ImageView (Image B) can be placed where ever the user desires along with scaling. Please see code below.

```
        imgMoveZoomCanvas.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View myView, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                                    
                // The user has pressed down on the Canvas Image
                CanvasX = event.getRawX();
                CanvasY = event.getRawY();
                CanvasDX = CanvasX - myView.getX();
                CanvasDY = CanvasY - myView.getY();


                start.set(CanvasX, CanvasY);
                pStop = start;
                mode = DRAG;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(mode == DRAG)
                {
                    // The user has moved the Canvas Image
                    // Check to see if the move is greater than the tolerance.
                    // If so, set the new value.
                    if(Math.abs(CanvasX - event.getRawX()) > TOLERANCE_X)
                    {
                        pStop.x = event.getRawX() - CanvasDX;
                        myView.setX(pStop.x);
                    }
                    if(Math.abs(CanvasY - event.getRawY()) > TOLERANCE_Y)
                    {
                        pStop.y = event.getRawY() - CanvasDY;
                        myView.setY(pStop.y);
                    }

                    myView.invalidate();

                    // In the event if the image has been zoomed prior to the DRAG
                    // keep the scale. The DRAG does not know it has been zoomed.
                    // Re-zoom the image.
                    if(saveScale != 1.0f)
                    {
                        // Animation Scale
                        Animation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(saveScale, saveScale, saveScale, saveScale, 0,0);//(float) mid.x, (float) mid.y);

                        // Zoom in/out to the Image
                        scaleAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
                        scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);

                        // Start the animation
                        myView.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
                    }

                }
                else if(mode == ZOOM)
                {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);

                    if (newDist > 10f) 
                    {
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;

                        // When the image gets too small it gets extremely
                        // difficult to move or scale.
                        if(scale <0.4f)
                        {
                            scale = 0.4f;
                        }

                        // Animation Scale
                        Animation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(saveScale, scale, saveScale, scale, 0,0);//(float) mid.x, (float) mid.y);

                        saveScale = scale;

                        // Zoom in to the Hand Image
                        scaleAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
                        scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);

                        // Start the animation
                        myView.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
                    }
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // The user is done with the image.
                mode = NONE;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
              {
                  oldDist = spacing(event);

                  if (oldDist > 10f) 
                  {
                      midPoint(mid, event);
                      mode = ZOOM;                               
                  }

                  break;
              }
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This works as expected. I can get Image B to be where I want it to be. However, when I want to save the 2 imageviews into one bitmap I am using a canvas which I will show the code momentarily. My problem is I am having a difficult time aligning the Image B with Image A. It is just slightly off. To be more clear, since ImageA is in the center I want the user to place ImageB where ever they want and how they want it scaled. Then I would like to recreate that image in a canvas and save the resulting canvas. The saving part works, but I need help on moving ImageB to where the user wanted. ImageB is just slightly off.

I thought by placing an offset would fix the problem, but it didn't. What I noticed that depending upon what image resolutions I am using whether it's my camera or some image I downloaded the offset is different. I am not sure why these images are not aligning.

Here is my saving function. I will highlight how I align the images in the canvas and maybe someone can point out what might be wrong.

```
ImageView imgA = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFrame);
            ImageView imgB = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCanvas);
            RelativeLayout rlCanvas = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlCaptureMe);

            Bitmap bmB = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgB.getWidth(), imgB.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Bitmap bmA = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgA.getWidth(), imgA.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            imgB.buildDrawingCache();
            bmB = imgB.getDrawingCache();

            imgA.buildDrawingCache();
            bA = imgA.getDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(rlCanvas.getWidth(), rlCanvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas cFinalImage = new Canvas(bm);

            Matrix matB = new Matrix();

            matB.postScale(saveScale, saveScale);
            matB.postTranslate(pStop.x * saveScale, pStop.y * saveScale);

            cFinalImage.drawBitmap(bmB, matB, null);
            cFinalImage.drawBitmap(bmA, new Matrix(), null);

            cFinalImage.concat(matB);
```

As you can see I am using a Matrix to position ImageB to where I need it to be. Have I overlooked something? I don't understand matrices very well so maybe I am doing something fundamentally wrong with them. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the solution to my problem was indeed a trivial one. What I noticed is that in my canvas all images were left most aligned. My layout had a padding for all the image views. Once I placed the padding into my matrix as shown below my images are not 90% correct. I think I may have to put just a few more adjustments down the line, but for the time being this is good enough.

```
matB.postTranslate((pStop.x * saveScale) + (imgB.getX() - (imgB.getX() / 2)), (pStop.y * saveScale) + (imgB.getY() - (imgB.getY() / 2)));
```

Now the canvas has the padding like the layout does.

Didn't realize that the answer was staring right at me.